# How to execute a same query for 7 days in Oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query

```
select count(*)
from purchases
where START_TIME>=TO_DATE('10-NOV-2017 00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI') AND START_TIME<TO_DATE('10-NOV-2017 01:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI') and 
      CLIENT_ID in (1,54);
```

and by using this I am gathering stats for an hour. But I am going to need stats everyday for the same time for past 7 days.

I mean, from above query I am gathering between `10-NOV-2017 00:00` and `10-NOV-2017 01:00` and similarly I need to gather for `09-NOV-2017 00:00` to `09-NOV-2017 01:00` and so on for past 7 days.

And it should print like

```
  Date        | Count  
+-------------+-------+
  10-NOV-2017 | 100    
  09-NOV-2017 | 110
```

Is it achievable ?

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated, please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
SELECT TRUNC (p.start_time), COUNT (*)
    FROM purchases p
   WHERE     START_TIME >= sysdate - INTERVAL '7' DAY  
         AND START_TIME <= sysdate  
          AND TO_CHAR (start_time, 'HH24:MI') IN ('00:00', '01:00')
         AND CLIENT_ID IN (1, 54)
GROUP BY p.start_time
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like

```
with
  dates as (select trunc(sysdate) - rownum + 1 d# from dual connect by level <= 7)
select
  d.d#, 
  sum(case when p.start_time is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from
  dates d, 
  purchases p
where
  p.client_id (+) in (1, 54) and
  p.start_time (+) between d.d# and d.d# + 1/24  
group by
  d#  
order by
  d#
```

Comment: You must using `ANSI` SQL join rather than this old joining technique.

Comment: XING, you're my boss, isn't you?

Comment: I don't know. But if you wish that , I dont have any objection :-)

Comment: client_id **(+)**

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
select p.*
from purchases p
where client_id in (1, 54) and
      start_time >= sysdate - 7 days and
      start_time < start_time and
      to_char(start_time, 'HH24:MI') in ('00:01', '00:02');
```

Comment: I have updated my question, could you please review ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT to_char(START_TIME,'DD-MON-YY') date,
  count(*) count
FROM
  purchases
 WHERE
  START_TIME  >=TO_DATE('10-NOV-2017 00:01','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI') -7
AND START_TIME <TO_DATE('10-NOV-2017 00:02','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI')
AND CLIENT_ID IN (1,54)
 group by to_char(START_TIME,'DD-MON-YY') ;
```